# Como limitar o tamanho(kb) de uma foto com JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho a seguinte dúvida, é possível limitar no lado do cliente com JS(ou jquery) o tamanho(kb) da foto?

Eu gostaria de limitar em 500kb no máximo usando o `input type="file"`

```
<input type="file" name="imagem"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em alternativa ao modo com jQuery, segue uma forma de se fazer usando Javascript puro (Vanilla). Lembrando que o tamanho está em bytes, isto é: 1024 byte = 1 kbyte

```js
var upload = document.getElementById("upload");
upload.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var size = upload.files[0].size;
    if(size < 1048576) { //1MB         
      alert('Permitido'); //Abaixo do permitido
    } else {           
      alert('Não permitido'); //Acima do limite
      upload.value = ""; //Limpa o campo          
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input id="upload" type="file" />
```

Comment: Legal funciona muito bem, e como limpar o input quando não for permitido?

Comment: Você pode setar o valor do elemento como vazio: upload.value = "";  
Farei a edição do código com essa linha...

Answer (score 2):

Veja este formato com JQuery:

```
$('#inputFile').bind('change', function(e) {
  var data = e.originalEvent.target.files[0];
  // Exibe o tamanho no console
  console.log(data.size + "is my file's size");
  // Ou faz a validação
  if(data.size > 500 * 1024) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 pontos. 1. seria interessante explicar que esta usando `jQuery` 2. Seria melhor trabalhar com `1024 * x` porque `if(data.size > 500000) {` vai dar menos que 500kb, 488kb quebrados

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Exato. KiB = 1024 bytes. 500KiB = 512000 bytes.